# mysql fetch different data on same query

Tags: mysql

I have seen a page on hierarchical data in Mysql which answered my 50% question. [Here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) is the link. Now, going threw the nested model, I wish I can also join other tables for each record on the nested table. For ex- I have the data stored in nested model hierarchicy which contains product details. Now, I wish I can see which user has bought which product and also fetch the user details from it.

For that very purpose, I added a field named `user_id` to the `nested_category` table, which contains the `user_id` of the `user_info` table. I want to first check the users table(detecting the one who is logged in), and then want to fetch out the details of what products he have.

For that purpose, I am using this query-

```
SELECT node.name, node.category_id, node.comment, node.user_id, (COUNT(parent.name) - (sub_tree.depth + 1)) AS depth
FROM nested_category AS node,
        nested_category AS parent,
        nested_category AS sub_parent,
        user_info,
        (
                SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
                FROM nested_category AS node,
                        nested_category AS parent,
                        user_info
                WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
                        AND node.user_id = user_info.user_id AND user_info.user_id = 1
                GROUP BY node.name
                ORDER BY node.lft
        )AS sub_tree
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
        AND node.lft BETWEEN sub_parent.lft AND sub_parent.rgt
        AND sub_parent.name = sub_tree.name
GROUP BY node.name
ORDER BY node.lft;
```

But this query doesn't run properly(By this, I mean to say that query is running but the deails are not in hierarchical manner). Can anyone help me?

**EDIT:**

I have tried modifying the code a bit and now the code is -

```
SELECT node.name, node.category_id, (COUNT(parent.name) - (sub_tree.depth + 1)) AS depth
FROM nested_category AS node,
        nested_category AS parent,
        nested_category AS sub_parent
        (
                SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
                FROM nested_category AS node,
                        nested_category AS parent,
                        LEFT JOIN user_info ON user_info.user_id = node.user_id
                WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
                        AND user_info.user_id = 1
                GROUP BY node.name
                ORDER BY node.lft
        )AS sub_tree
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
        AND node.lft BETWEEN sub_parent.lft AND sub_parent.rgt
        AND sub_parent.name = sub_tree.name
GROUP BY node.name
ORDER BY node.lft;
```

Which now produces the result something like this-
[image: mysql result]

which now have following things to consider-

- The button effect on category_id(WHY?)
- The wrong calculation of depth even when I am using user_id now to produce the output.

Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is MySQL database I suggest you to use proper group by fields. Because in the select clause you have mentioned so many fields, but in group by only 'node.name'. In all the other databases (Oracle/SQLServer,..) this query will throw error but not in MySQL.

But this single grouping will change the result and ordering.

If I understood correctly, you are getting the proper result only order is different. Normally the orderby 'node.lft' will work fine.

So please try with the proper grouping and update the result.